# App Store upload issue when using firebase

Tags: ios, archive

When trying to upload an Archived App to the iOS App Store, I am getting this error below:

> iTunes Store Operation Failed. No suitable application records were
>   found. Verify your bundle identifer
>   'org.cocoapods.GoogleToolboxForMac'

The app is using Firebase for remote notifications. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you setup the app in itunesconnect.apple.com?

Comment: Yes I have @yonasstephen

Comment: did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a new Bundle Identifier in the Developer Portal

[image]

Then pick it, and in this case it would be com.maniac-games.lowdown

Comment: this is an update to an app previously on the app store, will it be a problem if I make a new Bundle ID?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately this does not work. I still cannot upload the archive to iTunes connect still getting the same error: iTunes Store Operation Failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifer 'org.cocoapods.GoogleToolboxForMac'

Comment: do I need to make a bundle identifier on iTunes connect for each pod that I am using in my pod file? Sorry this responses is so late, I am still having this same issue.